# How to write completion handler in Swift with animation.

Tags: ios, swift

I have an animation, and when its complete I want to remove it from its superView. However I just can't get my head around the completion handler syntax for Swift. This animation is written in a `UIView` subclass.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: .CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: { self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 500)},
        completion: /*Magic Code here??*/)
```

I want to call `self.removeFromSuperView()` as the parameter for `completion`, however after reading many articles online I still cannot achieve this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.5,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: .curveEaseInOut,
    animations: { self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500) },
    completion: { [weak self] finished in
        self?.removeFromSuperview()
    })
```

The completion closure takes one argument, a `Bool` (called `finished` in the code above) indicating whether the animation actually completed, or was interrupted.

It's worth considering that since you are referencing `self` in the completion closure, it is *possible** that the animation may affect the lifetime of your view (consider that the animation is still running when the view would otherwise be deallocated, but the closure's strong reference is keeping the view alive). For this reason I included a capture list to ensure a weak reference to `self` is used.

**Possible, but perhaps unlikely... the view should only be deallocated in response to being removed from the view hierarchy, which I would expect to implicitly cancel the animation anyway and call the completion closure with `finished == false`. However, I would personally err on the side of caution and include `[weak self]` anyway, because I'm paranoid.*

Comment: It's good to keep in mind, but you don't need to use [unowned self] in this case because you're not creating a reference in self to the animation

Comment: There is a reference to `self` in both the animation and completion closures (so there should also be a capture list in the animation closure, in fact).

Comment: In order for it to create a cycle, self would also have to retain a reference to the animation or the closure, which it doesn't here. For example, if you were to assign the closure parameter to a class property, then you would have to worry about a strong reference cycle.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. Rather than retain cycle, I meant to imply that the closures capture a reference to `self` which could affect the lifetime of the view if the animation is still running when the system would otherwise want to deallocate it. Thinking about it, this is unlikely since the view would probably only be deallocated in response to being removed from the view hierarchy, which I would expect to implicitly cancel the animation anyway (calling the completion closure with `finished == false`).

Comment: And actually, if the lifetime _was_ affected, and the animation _wasn't_ cancelled, then using `unowned` would result in a crash, because the closure would not expect `self` to be `nil`. If anything, `weak` should be used, but you're likely right that the capture list is completely unnecessary. That's the last time I write an answer while on the phone to PayPal customer support... ;)

Comment: Swift 4 - Replace "[weak self] finished in" with "complete in"

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie I agree that the capture list (`[weak self]`) most likely isn't needed in the above situation (see the * note at the bottom of the answer), though the name of the closure parameter is unimportant (I would more normally use `_ in` because the param isn't used anyway, but have put it there for edifying purposes). But these changes aren't a Swift 4 concern and the code above will compile and work in Swift 4 without negative side-affects.

Comment: If you use [weak self] you will have to mark off any use of "self" as an optional. Also replacing "[weak self] finished in" with "complete in" is way cleaner and less to worry about.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie Indeed, `self` is optional when using `[weak self]`, and the code above reflects that. Also, this is a less important point, but the parameter name `finished` is more accurate here than `complete` in iOS nomenclature – the _completion_ handler is called when the animation _ends_, regardless of whether or not it _finished_. In other words, the term "finished" is indicating whether or not the animation reached the destination it was set up to drive towards; "complete" is less accurate, as by definition the animation has completed (ended) when the completion handler is called.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: .CurveEaseInOut,
    animations: { self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 500)},
    completion: { complete in
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: .curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: { self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500) },
                           completion: { (finished) in self.removeFromSuperview() })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0.1,
        options: .CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: 
     { self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 500)},
        completion: { _ in self.removeFromSuperview() })
```